# Is there a way to use pptx-python with python verion 3.7 and make exe with pyinstaller?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, python-pptx

ppt.py:

```
from pptx import Presentation

newPPT = Presentation()

newPPT.save("MyPPT.pptx")
```

converting to exe: `cmd == pyinstaller --onefile ppt.py`

once ready, the error is:

```
exception pptx.exc.PackageNotFoundError Raised when a package cannot be found at the specified path.
```

in the pptx package's [doc](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/install.html#:%7E:text=Currently%20python%2Dpptx%20requires%20Python,and%203.6%20on%20Travis%20CI).

is there a way to make it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue and finally figured how to fix it based on a similar issue:  https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/289

The solution is to edit the spec file.
To generate the spec file (if you don't have one already) run:

```
pyi-makespec --onefile yourprogram.py
```

open and edit the sepc file:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys # added line
from os import path # added line
site_packages = next(p for p in sys.path if 'site-packages' in p) # added line

block_cipher = None

# add in template in datas
a = Analysis(['your_file.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Desktop'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[(path.join(site_packages,"pptx","templates"), "pptx/templates")],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
# rest of the file doesn't need any modification
```

Finally generate the exe with:

```
pyinstaller your_spec_file.spec
```

(Tested on windows 10 machine running python 3.6.4)

Comment: I am doing something similar, but in my case, I need to use my own pptx template, rather default one. Have you tried this with using non-default pptx templates?

Comment: No I haven't. Sorry